# D3 example not working

Tags: d3.js

I just copy pasted this from the first example in here:
http://www.recursion.org/d3-for-mere-mortals/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>

<!--<script src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>-->
<script src="/d3/d3.v3.js"></script>

<div>
    <script>

        var rectDemo = d3.select("#rect-demo").
                append("svg:svg").
                attr("width", 400).
                attr("height", 300);

        rectDemo.append("svg:rect").
                attr("x", 100).
                attr("y", 100).
                attr("height", 100).
                attr("width", 200);

        d3.selectAll("body").append(rectDemo) ;

    </script>
</div>


</body>
```

and it shows nothing on the page. I am sure I am doing something stupid here but this is my first example and can't figure out what is going it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script attempts to draw the rectangle in a `svg` element that's added inside the (already existing) element with `id="rect-demo"`.

Therefore, you need to have an HTML element (for example a `<div>`) with the appropriate `id`:

```
<div id="rect-demo"> </div>
```

See this live demo: http://jsbin.com/enisen/2/edit